# Reusing custom layer doesn't add parameters to model.summary?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I've created a custom layer using layer subclassing. This layer is comprised by a series of specific dense layers and has the same sized inputs as outputs. I hope to stack these one after another such that they all have independent, trainable, weights and biases.

This custom layer is used in a model built via the model subclassing api. When I use the layer twice within the call method of the model subclass (ie, when I use self.custom_layer below twice right after one another), the model.summary() printed at the end of training only shows one of these layers and only lists the number of parameters for one of them.

However when I use separate names for instances of my custom layer (as shown below) then the model.summary() shows the two layers as separate and shows an increase in the number of parameters.

```
class custom_model(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.custom_layer = custom_layer()
        self.custom_layer_2 = custom_layer()
        self.dense64 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64)
        self.dense60 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(60)

    def call(self, inputs):
        out = self.custom_layer(inputs)
        out = self.custom_layer_2(out)
        out = self.dense64(out)
        out = self.dense60(out)

        return out
```

So what is going on with using the same name twice? By using self.custom_layer twice am I effectively only training the first one of these layers and creating a single loop back in my model? Or is there a bug in model.summary() with calling something with the same name twice and I'm training two completely separate instances of this layer independently as I hope it will do?

Comment: Please provide a full code example that reproduces the questionable behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `weights` remain the same when the layer is reused so trainable parameters are not added to `model.summary()`. I am surprised to see that you are not getting an error of shapes of input and output of custom layer and previous and next being incompatible. But that could be due to the layers being `Dense`. If you had been using `Conv2D` or any other such layers, you would have gotten an error.

Try giving unique names to each layer even if u reuse the code. That will initialize fresh and new weights to the layer and will add parameters to `model.summary()`